# Is it appropriate to raise an EnvironmentError for os.environ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, environment-variables

When `os.environ` is given the name of an environment variable that is not set, it throws a `KeyError`:

```
In [1]: my_value = os.environ['SOME_VALUE']

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0573debe183e> in <module>()
----> 1 my_value = os.environ['SOME_VALUE']

~/blah/ve/lib/python3.6/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    667         except KeyError:
    668             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 669             raise KeyError(key) from None
    670         return self.decodevalue(value)
    671 

KeyError: 'SOME_VALUE'
```

I get that a `KeyError` is raised because `os.environ` is like a dict, but in an application that needs `SOME_VALUE` to be set, I want to raise a more informative error when the user has neglected to set it.  One option is to raise an `EnvironmentError` with a more informative message:

```
try:
    my_value = os.environ['SOME_VALUE']
except KeyError:
    raise EnvironmentError('SOME_VALUE environment variable needs to be set to import this module') from KeyError

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
KeyError: 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-406772b14ea9> in <module>()
      2     my_value = os.environ['SOME_VALUE']
      3 except KeyError:
----> 4     raise EnvironmentError('SOME_VALUE environment variable not set') from KeyError

OSError: SOME_VALUE environment variable not set
```

It is curious to me that this raises an `OSError`.  The Python 2.7 documentation says `EnvironmentError` is the base class for `OSError`, and that base exceptions "...are only used as base classes for other exceptions."  In Python 3.6 documentation, [`EnvironmentError` is listed among concrete exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html?highlight=environmenterror#EnvironmentError), but without any documentation for the error class itself.  Questions:

1. Is it even appropriate to use `EnvironmentError` in this case?  Should I be using some other built-in error, or maybe a custom error?
2. Is `EnvironmentError` a base error class in Python 3.6?
3. Why does `OSError` get raised instead of `EnvironmentError`?

Comment: Your questions 2 and 3 are actually answered in your link, right above the anchor: `The following exceptions are kept for compatibility with previous versions; starting from Python 3.3, they are aliases of OSError.`. If you don't want to use/see the OSError then create your own. However, I would stick with the OSError, it seems appropriate in this context. Given the fact that EnvironmentError is just kept for compatibility in Python >= 3.3 I consider its use in Python 3.6 not appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

I sense a bit of confusion as to what "EnvironmentError" is. It does not relate to environment variables. The original meaning (in Python 2) for [exception `EnvironmentError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EnvironmentError) is:

> The base class for exceptions that can occur outside the Python system: `IOError`, `OSError`.

With [PEP 3151](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/), the IO and OS exceptions were re-worked for Python 3.3, such that they all use [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) as a base class. `EnvironmentVariable` is kept as an alias of `OSError` for backwards compatibility.

---

Some appropriate suggestions for exceptions related to environment variables could be:

- [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError) - this is a bit of a "miscellaneous" exception type, but it is perhaps appropriate if the local running environment does not have the variable set.
- [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) - the environment variable is set, but there is an exception with its value.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use

```
my_value = os.getenv("SOME_VALUE")
```

It will just return None if it doesn't exist.  And if you want, you can throw your own errors.

Comment: OP is asking which error type is appropriate here.